# Deriving the harmonic series function with the difference quotient: where did I go wrong?

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, derivatives

$$f(x) = \frac 1x$$

$$f'(x) = -\frac{1}{x^2}$$

$$\begin{align} f''(x) = \frac{-1/(x+d)^2 + 1/x^2}{d} &= \frac{-1/(x^2 + 2xd + d^2) + 1/x^2}{d} \\[2ex] &= \frac{-1/x^2(1+ 2x^{-1}d +d^2x^{-2}) + 1/x^2}{d}  \\[2ex] &= \frac{-1 + 1 + 2x^{-1}d + d^2x^{-2}}{dx^2 + 2xd^2 + d^3} \\[2ex] &= \frac{ 2x^{-1}d + d^2x^{-2}}{dx^2 + 2xd^2 + d^3} \\[2ex] &= \frac{ 2d }{dx^3 + 2x^2d^2 + xd^3} + \frac{d^2}{dx^4 + 2x^3d^2 + d^3x^2} \\[2ex] &= \frac{2}{x^3 + 2x^2d + xd^2} + \frac{d^2}{dx^4 + 2x^3d^2 + d^3x^2}  \end{align}$$

$$ \lim_{d\rightarrow 0} \frac{2}{x^3 + 2x^2d + xd^2} + \frac{d^2}{dx^4 + 2x^3d^2 + d^3x^2} = \frac{2}{x^3}$$

---

$$\begin{align} f'''(x) 
&= \frac{2/(x+d)^3 - 2/x^3}{d} \\[2ex] 
&= \frac{2/(x^3 + 3x^2d + 3xd^2 + d^3) - 2/x^3}{d } \\[2ex] 
&= \frac{2/x^3(1 + 3x^{-1}d + 3x^{-2}d^2 + x^{-3}d^3) - 2/x^3}{d } \\[2ex] 
&= \frac{2 -1 - 3x^{-1}d - 3x^{-2}d^2 - x^{-3}d^3}{x^3d + 3x^2d^2 + 3xd^3 + d^4} \\[2ex] 
&= \frac{1 - 3x^{-1}d - 3x^{-2}d^2 - x^{-3}d^3}{x^3d + 3x^2d^2 + 3xd^3 + d^4} \\[2ex] 
&= \frac{ -3x^{-1}d }{x^3d + 3x^2d^2 + 3xd^3 + d^4} + \frac{1 - 3x^{-2}d^2 -x^{-3}d^3}{x^3d + 3x^2d^2 + 3xd^3 + d^4 } \\[2ex] 
&= \frac{-3x^{-1}d }{x^3d + 3x^2d^2 + 3xd^3 + d^4} + \frac{1 -3x^{-2}d^2 -x^{-3}d^3 }{x^3d + 3x^2d^2 + 3xd^3 + d^4} \\[2ex] 
&= \frac{-3 }{x^4 + 3x^3d + 3x^2d^2 + xd^3} + \frac{1 -3x^{-2}d^2 -x^{-3}d^3}{x^3d + 3x^2d^2  + 3xd^3 + d^4 } 
\end{align} $$

$$\lim_{d \rightarrow 0} \frac{-3 }{x^4 + 3x^3d + 3x^2d^2 + xd^3} + \frac{1 -3x-x^{-2}d^2 - x^{-3}d^3}{x^3d + 3x^2d^2 + 3xd^3 + d^4} = -\frac{3}{x^4}$$

This is wrong, as $f'''(x) = \frac{-6}{x^4}$. Where did I go wrong?

Comment: It would be good that you explain what you’re doing. You’re mixing tons of equations, confusing equalities with limits. This is not making your readers willing to look at all the details! Moreover, you are expanding terms were such expansion adds complexity rather that simplification, i.e. for the denominators. At the end, you’re missing to factor $2$…

Comment: You cannot write $f''(x)=$, $f'''(x)=$ without having a $\lim_{d \to 0}$ in the expressions.

Comment: @mathcounterexamples.net Completely forgot the factor of $2$, thanks. I didn't bother to include the limits as I thought them implicit (this is just an informal sketch).  When you say I'm missing equations, are you referring to skipped algebraic steps? Because surely one can skip some if they're easy to see? This is not intended as a proof, just a sketch. I wasn't even going to post it, until I saw it was incorrect and was unable to find the point of error (I am too sleepy I guess). Could you elaborate on when I've expanded in a bad way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$2\cdot 3 = 6$,
not $3$.

You forgot to multiply that outer 2
by the inner 3.

Answer (score 1):

$$\lim _{d\to \:0}\left(\frac{\frac{2}{\left(x+d\right)^3}-\frac{2}{x^3}}{d}\right)=\lim _{d\to 0}\left(\frac{\frac{2}{\left(x+d\right)^3}-\frac{2}{x^3}}{d}\times \frac{\left(x+d\right)^3}{\left(x+d\right)^3}\right)$$
$$\lim _{d\to \:0}\left(\frac{\frac{2}{\left(x+d\right)^3}-\frac{2}{x^3}}{d}\right)=\lim _{d\to 0}\left(\frac{2-\frac{2\left(x+d\right)^3}{x^3}}{d\left(x+d\right)^3}\right)$$
$$\lim _{d\to \:0}\left(\frac{\frac{2}{\left(x+d\right)^3}-\frac{2}{x^3}}{d}\right)=\lim _{d\to 0}\left(\frac{2-\frac{2\left(x+d\right)^3}{x^3}}{d\left(x+d\right)^3}\times \frac{x^3}{x^3}\right)$$
$$\lim _{d\to \:0}\left(\frac{\frac{2}{\left(x+d\right)^3}-\frac{2}{x^3}}{d}\right)=\lim _{d\to 0}\left(\frac{2x^3-2\left(x+d\right)^3}{dx^3\left(x+d\right)^3}\right)$$
$$\lim _{d\to \:0}\left(\frac{\frac{2}{\left(x+d\right)^3}-\frac{2}{x^3}}{d}\right)=\lim _{d\to 0}\left(\frac{2x^3-2\left(x+d\right)\left(x+d\right)\left(x+d\right)}{dx^3\left(x+d\right)^3}\right)$$
$$\lim _{d\to \:0}\left(\frac{\frac{2}{\left(x+d\right)^3}-\frac{2}{x^3}}{d}\right)=\lim _{d\to 0}\left(\frac{2x^3-2\left(x^2+d^2+2xd\right)\left(x+d\right)}{dx^3\left(x+d\right)^3}\right)$$
$$\lim _{d\to \:0}\left(\frac{\frac{2}{\left(x+d\right)^3}-\frac{2}{x^3}}{d}\right)=\lim _{d\to 0}\left(\frac{2x^3-2\left(x^3+xd^2+2x^2d+dx^2+d^3+2xd^2\right)}{dx^3\left(x+d\right)^3}\right)$$
$$\lim _{d\to \:0}\left(\frac{\frac{2}{\left(x+d\right)^3}-\frac{2}{x^3}}{d}\right)=\lim _{d\to 0}\left(\frac{2x^3-2x^3-2xd^2-4x^2d-2dx^2-2d^3-4xd^2}{dx^3\left(x+d\right)^3}\right)$$
$$\lim _{d\to \:0}\left(\frac{\frac{2}{\left(x+d\right)^3}-\frac{2}{x^3}}{d}\right)=\lim _{d\to 0}\left(\frac{-2xd^2-4x^2d-2dx^2-2d^3-4xd^2}{dx^3\left(x+d\right)^3}\right)$$
$$\lim _{d\to \:0}\left(\frac{\frac{2}{\left(x+d\right)^3}-\frac{2}{x^3}}{d}\right)=\lim _{d\to 0}\left(\frac{-2xd-4x^2-2x^2-2d^2-4xd}{x^3\left(x+d\right)^3}\right)$$
$$\lim _{d\to \:0}\left(\frac{\frac{2}{\left(x+d\right)^3}-\frac{2}{x^3}}{d}\right)=\lim _{d\to 0}\left(\frac{-6xd-6x^2-2d^2}{x^3\left(x+d\right)^3}\right)$$
$$\lim _{d\to \:0}\left(\frac{\frac{2}{\left(x+d\right)^3}-\frac{2}{x^3}}{d}\right)=\frac{-6x\left(0\right)-6x^2-2\left(0\right)}{x^3\left(x+0\right)^3}$$
$$\lim _{d\to \:0}\left(\frac{\frac{2}{\left(x+d\right)^3}-\frac{2}{x^3}}{d}\right)=\frac{-6x^2}{x^3\left(x\right)^3}$$
$$\lim _{d\to \:0}\left(\frac{\frac{2}{\left(x+d\right)^3}-\frac{2}{x^3}}{d}\right)=\frac{-6x^2}{x^6}$$
$$\lim _{d\to \:0}\left(\frac{\frac{2}{\left(x+d\right)^3}-\frac{2}{x^3}}{d}\right)=\frac{-6}{x^4}$$